# ASP.Net MVC 3 ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am just getting started with ASP.Net MVC 3 and am confused on this point.

In some examples when an action in a controller is run that contains inputs then a check is made to ensure ModelState.IsValid is true. Some examples do not show this check being made. When should I make this check? Must it be used whenever an input is provided to the action method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Must it be used whenever an input is provided to the action method?

It is exactly when you are using a view model provided as action argument and this view model has some validation associated with it (for example data annotations). Here's the usual pattern:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the model is not valid => we redisplay the view and show the
        // corresponding error messages so that the user can fix them:
        return View(model);
    }

    // At this stage we know that the model passed validation 
    // => we may process it and redirect
    // TODO: map the view model back to a domain model and pass this domain model
    // to the service layer for processing

    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's mostly used for actions tagged with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

imho view models should always be validated (and therefore always have some kind of validation, usually DataAnnotation attributes).

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required] // <-- this attribute is used by ModelState.IsValid
    public string UserName{get;set;}
}
```

If you are interested in error handling in MVC, I've [blogged about it](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/) a couple of days ago.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking but it's not quite correct to say that the `[Required]` attribute is used by `ModelState.IsValid`. It is used by the default model binder which inserts error messages into the ModelState when binding the request values to the view model.

Comment: I know, but imho it's not relevant for a new user that just wants to get basic validation working.

Comment: IMHO we should be as precise as possible even with new users. For example, the way you put this comment in your answer, people unfamiliar with the internal working of ASP.NET MVC might think that it is the `ModelState.IsValid` call that triggers validation which obviously is not true. For example I have seen people asking why does ModelState.IsValid always returns true, well, it was because their actions were not taking any view model as argument, so the default model binder wasn't adding any potential error messages to the model state.

Comment: In that case it's not the model binder that does the validation but the `ModelValidationProvider` which has been register by using `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add()`. The default provider is called `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider`.

Comment: Now I agree, it's the default model binder's `SetProperty` method which calls the `Validate` method on each model validator provider that has been registered.